# setting up color to the item in listFragment

Tags: android

I am using **Simple Cursor adapter** to fill a list in **sherlockListFragment**.i had done that with loaders.But when i am trying to add a color to the text in the List.i am getting **Java.lang.Null.pointer** exception.And my java code is

```
    @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("live", "onActivityCreated");
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    setEmptyText("Loading...");

      SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder vb=new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View arg0, Cursor arg1, int arg2) {
            Log.i("alls","inside set View Value");
            View inflate=getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.live_list_stock,null);
            TextView tv=(TextView)inflate.findViewById(R.id.lpercent);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            //String i=tv.getText().toString();
            //Log.i("alls",(i));
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
        };


    liveMyStocksadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.live_list_item, null, new String[] {DBConstants.NAME,DBConstants.YSYMBOL,DBConstants.PRICE,DBConstants.PERCENT,DBConstants.DATE,DBConstants.TIME,DBConstants.OPEN,DBConstants.HIGH,DBConstants.LOW,DBConstants.VOLUME}, new int[] {R.id.lname,R.id.lysymbol, R.id.lprice,R.id.lpercent,R.id.ldate,R.id.ltime,R.id.lopen,R.id.lhigh,R.id.llow,R.id.lvolume},0);
    setListAdapter(liveMyStocksadapter);

    mycontext=this;
    getActivity().registerReceiver(FragmentReceiver1, new IntentFilter("fragmentupdater"));
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    liveMyStocksadapter.setViewBinder(vb);
```

Thanks for any help..

Comment: can you put stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to inflate your views when using view binders, SimpleCursorAdapter will do it for you. All you have to do is set the values (and only when they aren't common values as images, concat strings, etc). Note: strings, ints and default unformatted values are set by default view binders. All you need is to create your adapter properly.

When implementing ViewBinder, all views you've inserted as parameters of new SimpleCursorAdapter will be passed to you as parameter of view value (arg0), as well as the cursor (arg1 in the right line) and the column (arg2).

Try something like this:

```
public boolean setViewValue(View arg0, Cursor arg1, int arg2) {
   switch(arg0.getId()) {
   case R.id.lpercent:
      ((TextView)arg0).setTextColor(Color.RED);
      return false; // so it will set text view with DBConstants.PERCENT
   case ...: // TODO: put here some view you don't want default view binder set and then return true
      ((TextView)arg0).setText("non default value: " + arg1.getString(arg2));
   return true;
   }
}
```